# adding a text input box to a c++ gui using dev C++

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

i am using the dev c++ standard windows application template, and being completely new to gui programming, i have no idea where to even begin. i looked online at the examples, and tried adding L"Edit" to the following code:

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Windows App",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );
```

however when i tried to add it it gave me this error. `invalid conversion from const char*' to DWORD'` is there anywhere where i can learn how to do this using just dev c++? i actually want to learn how to do this from scratch and DO NOT want to use a builder. for those of you who use dev c++ how would i add a text input box to the standard windows gui template that they have?

Comment: If you want to learn Windows programming using the raw C API, then ["Programming Windows"](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Edition-Microsoft-Series/dp/157231995X) is the guy you're looking for, it covers all this stuff at the ground-zero level you appear to be interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your arguments to CreateWindowEx must be wrong.  Which line is the error on?  Is there any more info?  You should consult the documentation on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx

If you are completely new to UI programming, I would recommend downloading Visual Studio Express for Desktop.  It has a visual UI designer and lets you program in Visual Basic, C#, or Visual C++.  The programs you get will not be native Win32 apps; they run on the .NET virtual machine but that is fine.  You can see the source code generated by the designer too.

Comment: the reason i dont want to use visual basic is because i want to stay away from using a builder so i can actually learn how to do this from scratch. but i will check it out. thank you

Comment: Well, if you use C# or C++ you can see the source code the builder generates, and I think it is way easier than using these native Windows API functions.  The .NET framework provides higher-level components and are much easier to use.

Comment: Even if you don't use the builder, you can still use the components of the .NET framework (e.g. System.Windows.Controls.ListView) from Visual Studio and it will probably make your life easier.